# Why cant we use "PrintStream.out.println()" instead of "System.out.println()", as 'out' belongs to 'PrintStream' class?

Tags: java

I am a Beginner to programming. I have this unusual doubt:

Tell me the difference between `System.out` and `PrintStream.out`, please.

Comment: This is a wrong duplicate! His primary question is why don't we use PrintStream.out in place of System.out?

Comment: nope this is a decent duplicate target because it answers the basic gist of the question; which should only have one clearly defined question to begin with, and there are at least 6 other questions in the "Related" side bar that are duplicate targets as well. I will close it as a dupe immediately if it gets reopened.

Answer (score 2):

1. `System` is a class that has a few static fields to provide your Java program access to very basic operating system facilities.
2. `OutputStream` is a class that provides methods to write binary data into a stream (such as a file or network connection).
3. `PrintStream` is a subclass of `OutputStream` that provides methods to print text and other types of variables (like `boolean` or `int`) to an underlying `OutputStream`. It converts Strings to binary for example (so that it can be written out).
4. `System.out` is an instance of `PrintStream` that is connected to the standard output stream.
5. The field `out` in `PrintStream` is (unlike `System.out`) not a static field. This means that you need an instance of `PrintStream` to access it. `myPrintStream.out` rather than `PrintStream.out`.
6. The field `out` in `PrintStream` instances is the underlying `OutputStream` that is being wrapped.

   This is intended for implementations of `PrintStream` to write their binary output to.

   It is also `protected`, so that it is only accessible to those implementations.

   You cannot access `System.out.out` (or `myPrintStream.out`) directly (but you don't need to, as `System.out` will forward everything you `write`)

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` is the standard way to print over console whereas `PrintStream` being a wrapper is more specifically used to write to network streams and files.

Comment: Hmm. `System.out` is a `PrintStream`, too.

Comment: I wonder if you get down voted for not mentioning something rather than writing something wrong?

Comment: Same thing happening to me. People are also voting to delete both questions. My guess is the "don't answer duplicates" crowd here (even though duplication itself is in doubt). Welcome to Stackoverflow. Used to be a much friendlier site back in the day.